# how to get return value from apscheduler jobs

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using apscheduler to arrange some jobs. Some of the jobs have return values after the job be executed. How can I get the return values from these jobs ? Does anyone has idea on this ? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is still [under development](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/265), but you can use global variables for now. Here's an example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

def fn():
    '''Increase `times` by one and print it.'''
    global times
    times += 1
    print(times)


sched = BlockingScheduler()
times = 0

# Execute fn() each second.
sched.add_job(fn, trigger=CronTrigger(second='*/1'))
sched.start()
```