# How to access return value from apscheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I can't quite piece together how to access the return values from scheduled jobs in apscheduler. The job needs to run at a different time each day, and I need the return value from today's job to schedule tomorrow's job.

This link ([how to get return value from apscheduler jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707997/how-to-get-return-value-from-apscheduler-jobs)) appears to be the best previous answer to this question. It suggests adding a listener to the scheduler. I've added a listener, but I'm not sure how to access it's return value. I can access the listeners attached to the scheduler, but I can't access their outputs. A listener, job_runs() in the code below, will print when a scheduled job runs.

Further, I know I need to access a JobExecutionEvent (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/events.html#module-apscheduler.events) which holds the return value from the function.

First, the function I want to access is run_all() where a bunch of operations are performed, but I just return True for the test case.

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED, EVENT_JOB_ERROR, JobExecutionEvent
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging


def run_all():
    return True


def job_runs(event):  # listener function
    if event.exception:
        print('The job did not run')
    else:
        print('The job completed @ {}'.format(datetime.now()))


def job_return_val(event):  # listener function
    return event.retval
```

Then, I setup the scheduler, add the listeners, and add the job. The trigger is set to run the function 1 minute after the job is added to scheduler.

```py
  scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
  scheduler.add_listener(job_runs, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
  scheduler.add_listener(job_return_val, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED)
  cron_args = datetime_to_dict(datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1))
  job = scheduler.add_job(run_all, "cron", **cron_args)
```

Next, I start the scheduler and print the scheduled job. Additionally, I setup logging so I know where the scheduler is.

```py
  test = scheduler.start()
  scheduler.print_jobs()
  logging.basicConfig()
  logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

With the logging enabled, the scheduler reports that the job is run and removed from the scheduler, as I expect it to. job_runs() prints the correct output to the console. And with breakpoints, I know job_return_val() is called. However, I have no clue where the value it returns is sent to. The function appears to be called in a different thread called APScheduler. I don't know much about threads, but that makes sense. However, I do not understand when the output from that thread is returned to the main thread.

Finally, I've tried instantiating a JobExceptionEvent with the code, job_id, jobstore, and scheduled_run_time accessible from the attributes of scheduler and job, but the JobExceptionEvent does not seem to have any knowledge that the event was run in scheduler. That also seems to make sense due to the threading described in the preceding paragraph.

Any help in sorting through this would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of listener is not used anywhere (see the [code](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/8a174843acb499d7f327cc49efa4e47bdddeb8da/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py#L818)), so there's no use to return any value anyway. If you need to schedule another job based on the value of previous job (acquired in the listener via the event object), you have to do it right in that listener.

**EDIT:** To illustrate how to do it (and prove it's possible), see this sample code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_ERROR, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


def tack():
    print('Tack! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


def listener(event):
    if not event.exception:
        job = scheduler.get_job(event.job_id)
        if job.name == 'tick':
            scheduler.add_job(tack)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_listener(listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

The output:

```
(venv) pasmen@nyx:~/tmp/x$ python test.py 
Tick! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:29.192420
Tack! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:29.195878
Tick! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:34.193145
Tack! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:34.194898
Tick! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:39.193207
Tack! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:39.194868
Tick! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:44.193223
Tack! The time is: 2019-04-03 19:51:44.195066
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! You may noticed I changed this from the accepted answer. See my comment on Alex's answer below for why. I actually did look at the code you linked to when I was trying to sort through this, but I just didn't spend enough time with it to come to your conclusion apparently. Anyways, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why is it not possible to add jobs from the listener? Any specific reason?

Comment: @SpencerWeston Please see my edited answer, I've added an example.

Comment: Hmm. For whatever reason, when I call scheduler in the listener in my script, I get a name error. However, your test file runs just fine on it's own. So, I must be messing up something on my end. Nevertheless, this is the correct answer. Thank you for the test script.

Comment: How about providing your script and the complete stack trace so we can find out the problem?

Comment: I figured out how to replicate the issue using your test script. Take the code under 'if __name__ == '__main__'' and place it in a function, new_func(). Then, call new_func() in main. That will create the name error. 

To fix my script, I removed the main() function and placed the code under 'if __name__ == '__main__'.  So, it appears that's just a scope issue, right?

Comment: Seems so, the scheduler instance has to be available, most conveniently as a global variable in this case.

Comment: it doesn't have to. You can bind the scheduler variable  to the callback function with partial or create a small class that embeds both the callback and the scheduler.

Comment: Just tried this code on APScheduler 3.9.1. I'm getting error:     if job.name == 'tick':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 3):

You can use global variables for now. Here's an example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

def fn():
    '''Increase `times` by one and print it.'''
    global times
    times += 1
    print(times)


sched = BlockingScheduler()
times = 0

# Execute fn() each second.
sched.add_job(fn, trigger=CronTrigger(second='*/1'))
sched.start()
```

Comment: This works, not sure what's the downside.

Comment: this is one of the hacks , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What you need would require the [stateful jobs feature](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/265) to be implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I originally accepted Tomas' answer, but after trying that solution, I realized it's not possible to schedule jobs from within the listener.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem a few days ago. My first solution was using keyword global, but not long before I realized it was problematic, because the variables defined outside the job could unexpectedly be changed, especially when they are local variables in a loop.

Then I thought about using listeners, too. But the callback passed into a listener takes only the event as a single argument, which means the only information you can get from the callback is the event itself, profoundly limiting what you could possibly do.

Finally I choose to pass a func to the task to be scheduled, which works fine to me. What you really have to do is just to use the return value of the scheduled task as an argument for the func, as the code below shows.

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

def job_with_return(a:int, b:int, callback_return):
    # You can do something heavier here with the inputs.
    result = a + b
    print(f'[in job] result is {result}')
    if callback_return:
        callback_return(result)

scheduler.add_job(func=job_with_return,
    trigger='date',
    args=(1, 2, lambda r: print(f'[out of job]: result is {r}')),
    run_date=datetime.now(),
    )

scheduler.start()
```

The output:

```
[in job] result is 3
[out of job]: result is 3
```

As to the request of OP,

> The job needs to run at a different time each day, and I need the
> return value from today's job to schedule tomorrow's job.

you can additionally feed the func with the scheduler as well as the time you want the task to run in tomorrow, so that you can arrange a schedule in the func.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
today = datetime.now()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(seconds=1)

def task_today(a:int, b:int, scheduler:BlockingScheduler, callback_return, tomorrow:datetime):
    # What we have to do today is to get the result and use it to schedule tomorrow's task.
    result_today = a + b
    print(f"[{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] (Today) The result is {result_today}.")
    scheduler.add_job(callback_return, 'date',
                      args=(result_today,),
                      run_date=tomorrow,
                      id='job_tomorrow')

def task_tomorrow(result_from_today:int):
    result_tomrrow = result_from_today * 2
    print(f"[{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] (Tommorow) The result is {result_tomrrow}.")

scheduler.add_job(func=task_today,
                trigger='date',
                args=(1, 2, scheduler, task_tomorrow, tomorrow),
                run_date=today,
                id='job_today')
    
scheduler.start()
```

The output:

```
[22:22:40] (Today) The result is 3.
[22:22:41] (Tommorow) The result is 6.
```

You can even make a daily task with a recursion.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
today = datetime.now()

def task_daily(result_yesterday:int, day_counter:int, scheduler:BlockingScheduler, callback_return):
    # You can do something heavier here with more inputs.
    result_today = result_yesterday + 2
    day_counter += 1
    tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=1)
    print(f"[{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] (day {day_counter}) The result for today is {result_today}.")
    scheduler.add_job(task_daily, 'date',
                        args=(result_today, day_counter, scheduler, callback_return),
                        run_date=tomorrow)

scheduler.add_job(func=task_daily,
                trigger='date',
                args=(0, 0, scheduler, task_daily),
                run_date=today)

scheduler.start()
```

The output:

```
[22:43:17] (day 1) The result for today is 2.
[22:43:18] (day 2) The result for today is 4.
[22:43:19] (day 3) The result for today is 6.
[22:43:20] (day 4) The result for today is 8.
[22:43:21] (day 5) The result for today is 10.
[22:43:22] (day 6) The result for today is 12.
[22:43:23] (day 7) The result for today is 14.
```